# I need aws_access_key_id and aws_secret_access_key for Amazon

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, boto3

I'm totally new to AWS.
I want to download an s3 bukcet into my EC2 instance but I am geeting this error

```
   raise NoCredentialsError()
    botocore.exceptions.NoCredentialsError: Unable to locate credentials
```

in order for that to work I need to specify `aws_access_key_id` and `aws_secret_access_key` but I don't know from where I can get them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run your code on an EC2 instance, you should setup [IAM role for Amazon EC2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html) with `arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonS3ReadOnlyAccess` policy. Hardcoding credentials into an EC2 instance is a bad security practice.

Once you setup the role, boto3 on the instance will be able to **automatically** get the AWS credentials from the role to access the S3.

Comment: Could you please explain to me how to add this role

Comment: @Yafaa I linked AWS docs, which explained this step by step.

Comment: okai I added this role but still the same issue on the EC2

Comment: @Yafaa Its not possible to get same issue if what you say is correct representation of your setup. If you get same error, it means your question is not representative of your actual code that you use.

Comment: Worked I just need to attach the role to the EC2 thanks